# how to start a JFrame completely hidden at program start up

Tags: java, swing, jframe

i am about to finish a program that starts 2 Jframes, one have to show up normally and another one has to hide immediately and show up only if the user clicks a button but there is a little problem if i start the program i clearly see both the JFrames showing up, but just after like less than 1 sec one jframe hides himself, now it's completely normal but i want it to be more normal by letting the jframe not showing up at all, i don't even want that 1 sec of just showing/hiding, how can i achieve this ? i just use in the constructor of the frame that has to show up this

```
    dsc = new Sconti("Frame");
dsc.setVisible(false);
```

Comment: Why not to start the second JFrame **after** the user clicks the button?

Comment: because the frame in question got a variable that has to be carried through the frames, it's a bit tricky to change all for now so i am trying to get the fastest solution even if it is not the best

Comment: well have you tried hiding it behind the first JFrame?

Comment: Can we see a bit more of example code to help reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setState%28int%29

`setState()` set to `Iconified` before making visible.

Comment: it iconifies the other frame too

Comment: How come? Did you make another frame as child frame?

Comment: yes I managed to solve that because in the child constructor I set the visible to true and in the father's frame I set the visibility of the child to false, so this caused it to just appear for a sec the hiding

Answer (score 0):

solved by setting up the setVisible to false in the Sconti constructor while i was doing it in the other jframe constructor